# rewrite rules for manage.py runserver like .htaccess for apache

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx

Using .htacess, we can redirect requests like this :

```
RewriteRule \.(?:txt)$  handle_txt.php
```

which redirects all requests from .txt to handle_txt.php which sends the output in the required manner.

I want to make this work for django apps, how can I do this?

I mean to say, for example when I am developing the app(using manage.py runserver), where should I write that rewriterule ?

I can use .htaccess if I use apache as server.
I can use nginx confs for redirecting if I use nginx.(Am I right?)
What about development version(manage.py runserver) ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#using-mod-rewrite-to-point-urls-at-fastcgi

Answer (score 1):

You can use django URL dispatcher for this. It's more "django way" and it will work fine on production server as well as on development  server. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/). Also on production server you need to disable processing of static files that match this the regular expression.